# Issue with PHP button activation

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to show a button in my page only if a certain condition is met. 
Also i want to run a query (`DELETE QUERY`) when i press that button.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['finduser_btn']) && $noerr) : 

    echo "<div class='green'>
        <button type='submit' class='btn' name='scoreDel'>Delete scores</button>
    </div>

    endif ?>
```

I use `$noerr` as FLAG to display or not the button if another button is pressed (the other button is not shown in code)

Well, how do i use `scoreDel` button to run a query like:

```
DELETE FROM scores 
WHERE name = '$username$;
```

I think i have some issue with `"` and `'` into the PHP echoing html tags but i'm not sure... I hope in some help, i'm getting mad. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: you're missing a `"` after `</div>`

Comment: When using HTML in a string it's better to use simple quotes for the string : `'<div class="green">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" name="scoreDel">Delete scores</button>
    </div>';`

Comment: the other part can be done with a submit form or an ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['finduser_btn']) && $noerr) : ?>

    <div class='green'>
        <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="finduser">
        <button type='submit' class='btn' name='scoreDel'>Delete scores</button>
        </form>
    </div>

<?php endif ?>
```

Use a `form` to submit the `button` tag. Also, write html outside of PHP code if possible.

Comment: It's working now, but i ask you the same thing. Now it's working but just for a while! When i press the the DELETE QUERY works but when i refresh i have all the ROWS back, why? i mean, it seems to work on the browser until i refresh. instead into the db it never changes

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['scoreDel'])) {
          $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username';";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);
         }`

Comment: Try the following: `if (isset($_POST['scoreDel'])) { $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE username = '$username';"; $results = mysqli_query($db, $query); }`

Comment: @ducajack Where is `$username` being defined, post that code.

Comment: It has been defined into the same file where i run the SQL query like that `$username = ""; `

Comment: yes good hint... it depend on $username because i tried to delete "daniel" scores and it worked. I have to understand what now...

Comment: So,  `$username = "";` means that `$username` is empty, you have assign value to it, first like `$usernmae = "abc123"`.

Comment: Oh no well that's the definition, i used to assign a value through `$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['finduser']);` (finduser is a form field) but in this case i just have a button into the form without field so i don't know how to send the username!

Comment: i replaced your input tag with `<input type="hidden" name="bll" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">` and it worked perfectly in my case (wanted hidden field with username already written on it) I thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

You need a form in order to submit your action.

```
echo '<form action="mypage.php" method="POST"><div class="green">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" name="scoreDel">Delete scores</button>
    </div></form>';
```

Comment: Also `username` should be somewhere here.

Comment: Up voted for using simple quotes for the HTML string (y)

Comment: Down voted for putting html into a string in a any form, just escape php and write it as normal html sheesh `if(true):?><div>your ide will love this</div><?php endif; ?>`

Comment: Now it's working but just for a while! When i press the the DELETE QUERY works but when i refresh i have all the ROWS back, why?

Comment: Because value of `$username` in a query is undefined.

Comment: undefined? i've used it many times in query like select or insert, but in this case (delete) it doesn't work.